# Gaussian integral $\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-2x^2} dx$

Tags: integration, gaussian-integral

How can I evaluate the Gaussian integral

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-2x^2} dx$$

The result that I'm getting (which is wrong) is:

Let's say

$$
I = \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-2x^2} dx
$$

Then

$$
I^2 = \left( \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-2x^2} dx \right)^2 = \int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-2(x^2+y^2)} dxdy = \int_{0}^{2 \pi} \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-2(r^2)} r dr d\theta
$$

Substitution:

$$
u = -2r^2\\
- \frac{du}{4} = r dr
$$

Therefore

$$
- \frac{1}{4} \lim_{a \to - \infty} \int_{0}^{2 \pi} \int_{0}^{-2a^2} e^{u} du d\theta
$$

Since

$$
\lim_{a \to - \infty} \int_{0}^{-2a^2} e^{u} du = -1
$$

Then

$$
- \frac{1}{4} \int_{0}^{2 \pi} \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{u} du d\theta = \frac{1}{4} \int_{0}^{2 \pi} d\theta = \frac{1}{4} \cdot 2\pi
$$

So

$$I = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}$$

The correct result should be

$$I = \frac{1}{4} \sqrt{2 \pi}$$

Where did I go wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: $\theta$ should vary from 0 to $\pi/2$.

Comment: @SangchulLee I see. Why is that Sangchul?

Comment: You have computed the integral on the whole real line. Now, since the integrand function is even, you must divide your result by $2$, and you get the correct result.

Comment: That's because the region $\{(x,y):x,y>0\}$ describes the first quadrant.

Comment: Change variables: $y = \sqrt{2}x$, then use the known value of the Gaussian integral. ( I know, that doesn't say where your calculation is wrong, so may not answer your question.)

Comment: @SangchulLee I see, thank you.

Comment: For future reference, if you have to evaluate the Gaussian integral when the coefficient of $x$ is not 1, differentiating under the integral is a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

Another Method to handle this problem (too long for a comment)

$$I=\int _{ 0 }^{ \infty  }{ { e }^{ -2{ x }^{ 2 } }dx } $$

Substitute: $x\rightarrow \sqrt { \frac { x }{ 2 }  } $

$$I=\frac { 1 }{ 2\sqrt { 2 }  } \int _{ 0 }^{ \infty  }{ { x }^{ \frac { -1 }{ 2 }  }{ e }^{ -x }dx } $$

By the definition of Gamma Function, we get: $$I=\frac { \Gamma \left( \frac { 1 }{ 2 }  \right)  }{ 2\sqrt { 2 }  } $$

Hence,

> $$\boxed{\int _{ 0 }^{ \infty  }{ { e }^{ -2{ x }^{ 2 } }dx }=\frac { \sqrt { \pi  }  }{ 2\sqrt { 2 }  } }$$

Comment: $x=(x/2)^{0.5}$?

Comment: @Upstart you are allowed to do so.

Comment: If this is confusing you, the expression "*substitute $x \to (x/2)^{0.5}$*" means: change variables from $x$ to $y=(x/2)^{0.5}$.